# Alignment of vertical subfigures

Tags: vertical-alignment, subfloats

I have five images as subfigures. All images are the same size. However, row 1 and row 2 don't align vertically.

[image]

I'd like to line up (a) and (d) and (b) and (e) if possible.
This is the code to produce the currently-seen image:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

    \newcommand{\plotfunc}[3]{
        \begin{subfigure}[t]{#3\textwidth}
            \caption{#2}
            \resizebox{1\linewidth}{!}{
                \includegraphics{../Images/GloveOfDoom/RFIDTag_Testing_Other_s}
            }
        \end{subfigure}
    }
    \begin{figure}
    \plotfunc{methods.a9a.0.64}{a9a}{0.3}
    \plotfunc{methods.webspam.0.0025}{webspam}{0.3}
    \plotfunc{methods.rcv1.0.000625}{rcv1}{0.3}
    \plotfunc{methods.news20.0.000625}{news20}{0.3}
    \plotfunc{methods.kddcup2010.0.01}{kddcup2010}{0.3}
    \caption{Training Time of Factorization machine with a bias term and $\lambda=0.01\lambda_{best}$}
    \label{fig:FMLambda-1func}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an empty line to indicate a linebreak and (assuming all your images have the same szie), they will be aligned.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newcommand{\plotfunc}[3]{%
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{#3\textwidth}
    \caption{#2}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \end{subfigure}
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
    \plotfunc{methods.a9a.0.64}{a9a}{0.3}
    \plotfunc{methods.webspam.0.0025}{webspam}{0.3}
    \plotfunc{methods.rcv1.0.000625}{rcv1}{0.3}

    \plotfunc{methods.news20.0.000625}{news20}{0.3}
    \plotfunc{methods.kddcup2010.0.01}{kddcup2010}{0.3}
    \caption{Training Time of Factorization machine with a bias term and $\lambda=0.01\lambda_{best}$}
    \label{fig:FMLambda-1func}
  \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]